# Reading file names from directory with SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, file-read

Using SystemVerilog I am trying to see if a file name already exists in my test directory.
For example I want to write a file called text_1a2b3c4d.txt but need it to have a unique name. The test will be run multiple times and a random hex number will be used in the file name.

I initially attempted to open the file with the following approach and check to see if a zero would be returned (which is does). The code completes, however, I get an warning when the file is not found, which I would like to avoid in the env I am working in.

```
module file_write;
   
    int                 file_status = 1;
    bit [31:0]          rand_id;
    string              s_rand_id;
    string              file_name;
  
  initial begin
     
    while (file_status !== 0) begin
        rand_id = $urandom();      // Generate rand 32 bit value
        s_rand_id.hextoa(rand_id); // convert rand 32 bit value to string for file name
        file_name = {"text_", s_rand_id, ".txt"}; // Create filename in format txt_rand#.txt
        file_status = $fopen(file_name, "r");
        if (file_status !==0) $display("Hex ID: %h already used, regenerating", rand_id);
        $fclose(file_status); // Close file descriptor
    end
    
    $display("End of section");
    
  end
endmodule
```

Is there a way to read all file names in a directory that way I could search for a name match? or are there other recommended ways to approach this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no lrm requirement to provide an error message for missing files. So, it is either tool-dependent or it happens at $fclose for null pointer. In the first case check documentation on your compiler and disable those warnings. In the second, move your fclose into the above 'if' statement by adding begin..end.

Comment: I believe it is a tool specific situation where it reports it as an error. I will look into disabling the warnings. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding a different approach which avoided the error. This involves using $system().

```
module file_write;
   
    int                 file_status = 1;
    bit [31:0]          rand_id;
    string              s_rand_id;
    string              file_name;
  
    initial begin
    
    while (file_status !== 0) begin
        rand_id = $urandom(); // Generates random 32-bit value
        s_rand_id.hextoa(rand_id);
        file_name = {"text_", s_rand_id, ".txt"}; // Create filename in format text_rand#.txt

        if($system($sformatf("test -f ./folder/%s", file_name)) == 0) begin // File exists
            $display("Hex ID: %h already used, regenerating", rand_id);
        end
        else begin // File does not
             file_status = 0;
        end
    end

    $display("End of section");
    
    end
endmodule
```

The test -f command returns 0 when the file exists. This method does not propagate any warning/error messages in my environment, which satisfies my requirements.